# Trying to get property of non-object Laravel BelongsTo

Tags: laravel-5

Tengo una clase HolidaysModel que tiene la siguiente relacion

```
public function user() {
     return $this->belongsTo('MolInterno\Users\UsersModel', 'id_user', 'id');
}
```

En el controlador Holidays hago:

```
 public function index() {
   $holidays = $this->holidaysRepo->search(array(), false, 'created_at', 'DES');

   return view('admin.holiday.index', compact('holidays'));
 }
```

En la vista hago:

```
@foreach($holidays as $holiday)                
  <tr class="text-center">
    <td>  {{$holiday->user->first_name}} </td>
    <td>{{date('d-m-Y', strtotime($holiday->start_date))}}</td>
    <td>{{date('d-m-Y',strtotime($holiday->end_date))}}</td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

El problema me lo da `$holiday->user->first_name` (Trying to get property of non-object), si elimino esto anda. Si hago `$holiday->user['first_name']` también anda.

Si hago  `{{getType($holiday->user)}}` me da como resultado OBJECT.

Y esto `{{$holiday->user}}` me devuelve:

```
{"id":45,"first_name":"Maria ","last_name":"Lopez","email":"maria@lopez.net ","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-02-03 09:00:48","updated_at":"2017-02-03 09:00:48"}
```

No entiendo porque no anda `$holiday->user->first_name` , siendo este un objecto y teniendo que acceder como array `$holiday->user['first_name']`

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código de `holidaysRepo`, método que llamas para crear tu variable `$holidays`? El mensaje de error te está diciendo que al hacer `<td>  {{$holiday->user->first_name}} </td>` el programa no reconoce `$holiday` como un objeto.

Comment: Ahi como puse en el codigo. Le paso compact('holidays'). Y luego hago el foreach @foreach($holidays as $holiday) . Ahi esta holiday

Comment: Ok. Como bien dices: _"Si hago $holiday->user['first_name'] también anda..."_ porque first_name está dentro del arreglo user, lo cual es lógico, ya que first_name es parte de un usario: `{"id":45,"first_name":"Maria ","last_name":"Lopez","email":"maria@lopez.net ","del...`, Si de todos modos quieres llamarlo como user->first_name tu arreglo debería tener un sub_nivel llamado first_name, algo así más o menos: `{"first_name": {"type": "string"},"last_name": {"type": "string"},"age": {"description": "Age in years","type": "integer","minimum": 0} }`

Answer (score 1):

Pude encontrar el error.

Al hacer $holidays[0]->user->first_name anda.

El error se da porque al recorrer el foreach hay una relacion que no tiene un usuario para holiday. Entonces al hacer $holiday->user->first_name da error.

Adentro del foreach agregue un if para saber si existe la relación y anda.

```
@foreach($holidays as $holiday)                    
  <tr class="text-center">
     <td>
           @if($holiday->user != null)
            {{$holiday->user->first_name}} {{$holiday->user->last_name}}
           @endif
     </td>

     <td >{{date('d-m-Y', strtotime($holiday->start_date))}}</td>
     <td >{{date('d-m-Y',strtotime($holiday->end_date))}}</td>                       
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: podrías pegar cómo quedó el `foreach` después del cambio?

Comment: Ahí agregue el foreach. @amenadiel

Comment: Gracias! Ojo, que podrías filtrar los NULL al usar el método `search` del repositorio

Comment: Como filtraría con el search los NULL? Porque eso me trae solo la relacion. Estoy usando no hace mucho el repositorio y hay métodos que me faltan, como hacer varios joins que los tengo que hacer manual nomas con eloquent. @amenadiel

Comment: Eloquent tiene un método `Model::whereNotNull('user')` pero para tu caso de uso no sé si opera sobre una relación o si en ese caso tienes que usar el query Builder que es más engorroso

Answer (score 1):

Con php 7 pudiera quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
@foreach($holidays as $holiday)                
  <tr class="text-center">
    <td>  {{$holiday->user->first_name ?? ''}} </td>
    <td>{{date('d-m-Y', strtotime($holiday->start_date))}}</td>
    <td>{{date('d-m-Y',strtotime($holiday->end_date))}}</td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

O con versiones anteriores funcionaría lo siguiente:

```
@foreach($holidays as $holiday)                
  <tr class="text-center">
    <td>  {{$holiday->user->first_name ? $holiday->user->first_name:''}} </td>
    <td>{{date('d-m-Y', strtotime($holiday->start_date))}}</td>
    <td>{{date('d-m-Y',strtotime($holiday->end_date))}}</td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Explica brevemente _qué hace este código_. Lee [answer].